# Is It Still Possible Get SharePoint 2013 Master status (MCSM)?

Tags: 2013, certification

I've checked [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsm-certification.aspx). It says that MCM is retired, but I'm not sure how to take master exams? Does anyone has any knowledge on this topic, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are the two paths available now: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/sharepoint-certification.aspx

Comment: Hi, Ribert... yea, I've researched it further. Looks like this is true. No more masters. Thanks a lot.